# AWS EC2 Apache Load Balancer Issue

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

We have 5 t2.medium instances on AWS, all the instances connect to MariaDB via RDS on a r4.xlarge instance.

The problem is that periodically the 5 instances suddenly stop working, Apache doesn't response anymore and we can't access via SSH.

We need to reboot all instances on the AWS Console to make them work again, the Load Balancer is an application lb, the server folder "/var/www" is on a EFS to share the project.

These are the images of the monitoring, we don't know why this happen so suddenly and how can we handle it.

The last issue was this morning the 5 instances stop working and the Load balancer to.

We share the monitoring of the last 12 hours.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Any advice?

Regards.

Comment: If you can't SSH into any of the instances, that is unrelated to the load balancer (unless you are trying to SSH *through* the load balancer, which would be wrong). At first I thought it would be CPU credit exhaustion, but from your screenshot it looks like that isn't the case. What exactly does you mean when you say the load balancer stops working?

Comment: You do not have any disk activity yet you are sending almost a Gbit per second. Are you running out of EFS credits? What do the Apache error logs show?

Comment: Usually when a system becomes unresponsive and you cannot even connect, it is caused by: 1) the system has crashed. 2) The CPU is maxed out at 100% 3) memory has been exhausted and the system cannot keep up with the required swapping / paging. Get to know your system's log files and dig into them. For AWS instances, look into resource limits also.

Comment: @MarkB the Load Balancer shows all the instances like "unhealthy"  for the main reason that the Health Checkers fails because all the instances stop working. Apache doesn't response anymore and if we need to access of one by one we can't do it we get a timeout connection via ssh, we need to restart the instances via AWS Console.

Comment: @JohnHanley the error log usually shows only PHP Script errors from the project nothing critical. How can i check if we runt out of credits on EFS?

Comment: You can retrieve your burst credit balance through the CloudWatch GetMetricStatistic API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html. You can set the Namespace parameter to "AWS/EFS" and the MetricName parameter to "BurstCreditBalance". Additionally, you can set up a CloudWatch alarm on your burst credit balance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/creating_alarms.html

Comment: @JohnHanley my burst credits are 2.31T my EFS has 440 GB